# Hellfire for unbelievers

Tags: islamic-philosophy, freedom-of-belief

Why does Allah punish unbelievers with hellfire for eternity, especially when he doesn't need to have anyone recognize or worship him?

Edit:The real question is why did it Allah make it such that we must worship him or burn eternally?

Comment: Allah does not need people to worship Him. But He does command that they do. And not worshiping Him is a crime that deserves punishment.

Comment: I guess what I meant to ask is why is it a crime that deserves punishment? Why did Allah make that a crime?

Answer (score -2):

actually there's no heaven and hell. they are the consequence of the man doing. if you read Holy Quran carefully you can see various examples. there is no heaven for you and me right now but we build our own heaven and hell after death with our actions. GOD only wants to save us so he says to worship him. when you know he is watching you and he is everywhere, or when you just look around yourself and see lots of things that he gave to you, you won't do something wrong anymore. you purely work for GOD to satisfy him.

Comment: Wow there's no heaven or hell? I believe that goes directly against the teachings of Islam as I'm pretty sure they are both physical places you go to. Also, doesn't each person have a place in heaven and another place in hell, and he ends up in one of the two? In addition, saying that God is everywhere I think is incorrect according to Islam as he is in a specific place above the 7 skies. It sounds like a deistic thing to say that he is everywhere.

Comment: @JohnDoe if you read Quran  correctly you find out that heaven and hell are made from people's action. just some abuser for their own good said lies like "wow you are going to a beautiful place with beautiful women"...dont you think its a little boring? i think the truth is beyond that.

Comment: This doesn't remotely come close to answering the question. I asked why did Allah make it such that we must worship him or burn eternally.